# How to toggle div?

Tags: javascript, toggle

I searched around stack overflow and I tried just about every topic - none of them worked. I'm trying to toggle the "inventory" div to block instead of none after you click the button "btnTwo". How would you do this? This is my current code:

```
<script>
function one()
{
    var newButton1 = '<button id="btnTwo" onclick="two()" >Pick up stick</button>';
    var newButton2 = '<button id="btnThree" onclick="three()">Leave it there</button>';
    document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = "You feel something on the ground, and you think it's a stick."+newButton1+newButton2;
    var myButton = document.getElementById('btnOne');
    myButton.onclick = four;
}

function two()
{
    document.getElementById("b").innerHTML="You pick up the stick. It might be useful for something."; 

    document.getElementById("btnTwo").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("btnThree").style.display = 'none';
}
function three()
{
    document.getElementById("c").innerHTML="You leave the stick on the ground and continue on.";

    document.getElementById("btnTwo").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("btnThree").style.display = 'none';
}

function four()
{
    document.getElementById("d").innerHTML="You feel a stick stuck to the wall with something like honey. Next to it is a few rocks.";
}
</script>

<div style="margin-left:15px; width:200px; margin-top:100px;">
    <button id="btnOne" onclick="one()">Feel around the cave</button>
</div>

<div id="inventory" style="margin-left:255px; width:200px; height:600px; margin-top:-15px; display:none;">
    Sticks: 
    <div id="stickNumber">1</div>
</div>

<div id="entire" style="margin-left:490px; margin-top:-22px; width:400px; height:600px;">
    <div id="d"></div>
    <div id="c"></div>
    <div id="b"></div>
    <div id="a"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
function two()
{
document.getElementById("b").innerHTML="You pick up the stick. It might be useful for something.";

document.getElementById("btnTwo").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("btnThree").style.display = 'none';

}
```

to

```
function two()
{
document.getElementById("b").innerHTML="You pick up the stick. It might be useful for something.";

document.getElementById("btnTwo").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("btnThree").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("inventory").style.display = "block";

}
```

[Updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/AdwPN/2/)

Comment: This is probably the most helpful one - but it removes all the text on the side if I click btnTwo

Comment: @user3050217 Can you be more specific about what you are trying to achieve?  The code in the example you gave removes the text

Comment: I'm trying to make it so that the inventory shows, but the text on the right still shows too.

Answer (score 0):

Well. If you want to toggle something you just need to first check the state of the object, and apply the oposite of what is set.

```
var el = document.getElementById('el'); //some div
var bt = document.getElementById('bt'); // some button
el.style.display = "block";

bt.onclick = function(){
    if(el.style.display == "block"){
        el.style.display = "none";
    }else{
        el.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FxXgL/)

You could also use some library like for instance jquery where this would be as easy like:

```
$("#bt").click(function(){
    $("#el").toggle();
})
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FxXgL/1/)

Answer (score 0):

For your case, you just need to add below script into the bottom of function two():

```
    document.getElementById("inventory").style.display = 'block';
```

I have test the code on safari and chrome.